# jQuery UI tabs, can't access objects in a new tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

Searching for hours on this, I must be doing something stupid.  jQuery UI v1.11.1.  Have a tab widget, my first tab is statically created inside my .html.  On that first tab, there is a button to create new tabs:

```
function addTab(tabTitle) {

    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    var ul = tabs.find("ul");
    var id = "tabs-" + tabCounter;
    $("<li><a id='" + id + "' href='server.html'>" + tabTitle.val().toUpperCase() + "</a></li>").appendTo(ul);
    tabs.tabs("refresh");

    var index = $("#tabs a[id='" + id + "']").parent().index();
    $("#tabs").tabs({ active: index}); // This successfully selects the new tab visually on the screen

    //$("#" + id).click(); // Tried selecting the tab this way also, same issue

    var curTabPanel = $('#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)');
    alert(curTabPanel.prop("id")); // This returns the ID of the first tab, not the tab selected on screen, not sure what that implies

    $("input").css("display", "none"); // This makes all the input fields disappear on the first tab, not on the tab selected on screen

    tabCounter++;
}
```

As you can see, I've tried multiple ways to switch to the new tab as the active tab, but both ways seem to only allow me to manipulate elements on the 1st (now hidden) tab - even though visually the new tab is selected on the screen.

Ultimately I need all of the jQuery handlers that I've defined on document ready to apply to the new elements in this new tab.

What am I doing wrong?

--edit--

If I create the elements on the new tab manually (instead of loading them from server.html), I am able to use jQuery to control the elements.

Is there a reason that loading tab contents via an external html file would make those elements non-accessible to jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: What is `#tabs`? `tabCounter`? Where is the `HTML`? `CSS`? (*if any*) required to reproduce..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add the div element of tab..

```
  tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
```

Comment: its an Ajax load, the div of the tab gets added automatically.. I see it properly on the screen and in firebug..